# Is it a good idea to identify objects by an unique member id?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, containers

My question is, how should I relate object to each other.

I've two vectors, `vector<Baby> babies` and `vector<Toy> toys`. Each baby and each toy has an unique member `int id`. Thus all babies and toys are numbered from 0 to n.

Now, each Baby has one preferred Toy and each Toy has a preferred Baby. Up to now, I used pointers: Baby has a pointer to his preferred Toy and this Toy has a pointer to the Baby. (that's ok, since I will never change the vectors)
However, what distinguishes the babies and the toys form each other is their ID, and not their location in the vector.

As I got along I questioned my design and found that pointers work, but they might lead to problems in the future. Contrary, if I use the ID I will be fine but I would need to have access to the whole babies or toys vectors.

Is there a common practice in such a situation? Is it good idea to use pointers? Should I write my own container that uses the ID in an intelligent way?

**Edit:**
I like to add, that I’ve considered a map to relate baby and toy. However I determine the relation of baby to toy (and the other way around) during runtime. To find this relation is a major part of the program. Therefore I'm not sure if I could use maps. However, I will look at it (haven't used it till now). What is more, the information about the preferred toy and baby must be part of the object, not (only) of a superiore data structure.

Comment: Have you thought about using a `std::map<int, int>` ? You could use the position of a baby in the vector as the `key` and the position of the corresponding toy in its vector as the `value`, especially if you don't change the vectors. Or if you don't want the positions, you could use the IDs as keys and values

Comment: If you haven't heard of "stringly-typed interfaces", I encourage you to look it up. Don't use `int` for every ID, instead make it so that a `BabyId` and `ToyId` are different types; you don't want to accidentally recycle a baby, do you?

Comment: Pointers are ok. Try to not use IDs at all - or only as a simple attribute like name etc...  Pointers are always unique, IDs can be mistakenly duplicated.

Comment: If you afraid of having leak pointers - then consider to use smart pointers (weak and shared_ptr)

Comment: If your "ID" is just an index into the vector then yes this is a good idea. Because then you won't have problems with vector reallocation moving the vector and invalidating your pointers. If it is more complicated, then you start to need a `std::map` recording the association between the ID and the vector index.

Comment: And yes to use a vector index you need a reference to the vector. If you want to make that simple you can wrap the vector reference and the index into one object. Now you essentially have a pointer with offset which is very useful for things like serialization or memory mapping.

Comment: @Zan Lynx, could you elongate?

Comment: I think this question would benefit from a bit more context about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using unique IDs for the relationships has some advantages.  The IDs can't dangle like a pointer or be out-of-bounds like a vector index. They can be easily serialized. They are not invalidated when the vectors are reallocated or reordered.

But they have some disadvantages too.  It is up to you to ensure they remain unique (using GUIDs can help with this).  They could also be very inefficient to work with. To find an object by ID you have to search the entire vector.  You could do one pass through the vector to create a lookup `map`/`unordered_map`/`vector` where the key is the ID and the value is a pointer to the object or index in the vector.

Comment: In my case it is no problem to lookup an element by ID, since they can have the corresponding location in the vector.

Comment: @dani OK, I thought you said what distinguished each object was its ID and not its position in the vector. In which case you are fine. The only downside then is your data structure is quite fixed, you can't easily delete objects or reorder them.

Comment: Well, i can reorder them if I use the ID. I will not destroy or create new objects. Just assign them to each other throughout the program.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a `std::map<Baby, Toy>`/`std::map<Toy, Baby>` or even a `std::unordered_map<Baby, Toy>`/`std::unordered_map<Toy, Baby>`.

```
#include <map>

std::map<Baby, Toy> babyMap;
std::map<Toy, Baby> toyMap;

// ...

babyMap[theBaby] = theToy;
toyMap[theToy] = theBaby;
```

If the `Baby` "happens" to prefer more than one toy, or viceversa, you may use `std::map<Baby, std::set<Toy>>`s/`std::map<Toy, std::set<Baby>>`.

P.D: Usually, `int`-style IDs are a bad code smell, and can lead to severe issues later on.

Answer (score -1):

> What about a vector of one of this structure?

```
struct BabyToy { Baby B;  Toy T;};
```

> or

```
class BabyToy
{
  public:
  Baby B;
  Toy T;

  BabyToy(Baby b, Toy t)
  {
     B=b;
     T=t;
  }
};
```

Comment: The question doesn't say whether a Toy prefers the same Baby that prefers the Toy, or indeed that only one Baby prefers a single Toy.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - You're right, my mistake was due to a misinterpretation of the question also because of my bad English: I thought it was a 1: 1 relationship between Baby and Toy ... Anyway, I'm new on this site and I apologize for the superficiality and haste of my answer ... in the future I will try to read more carefully the questions giving my answer only after understood the question. PS: I added this comment just now because when I provided my answer I had just recorded and not yet know all the rules (and the risk of being voted negative!)

Answer (score -1):

SORRY but in your question J read:

> Now, each Baby has one preferred Toy and each Toy has a preferred
>   Baby.

Comment: @ KemyLand - I'm sorry, this was not to be an answer, but a comment to add to my previous answer (I'm new to this site, I have some difficulty in English and I learned the rules by reading Support Center> Answering just now)